# Active Directory groups with Samba suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba

Over the past week, our users have been reaching out complaining that they can't upload/modify files on the company file server. Specifically, they'll try dragging files onto the share through Windows Explorer and will be faced with 'Access Denied'.

The fileserver is a Ubuntu VM that's joined to the Windows domain using the following documentation [Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member.](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member) Admittedly I used our old smb.conf(**see below**) from the old file server, as my understanding of Linux/Samba is very limited and needing to get the share up and running as soon as possible.

Here's what I've done so far

**1.** SSHd into the file server and checked the permissions of a folder that was known to be having issues.

`ls -ll directory_in_question`

`drwxrwsr-x 12 root  name_of_active_directory_group 4096 Dec 17 15:21  ./`

*Noticed that 'name_of_active_directory_group' seems to be correct, however the members of this group still can't upload files to this location through Explorer.*

**2**. Checked to see if I can even access the group using `getent group 'name_of_active_directory_group`, and I'm given `name_of_active_directory_group:*:10083:username_one,username_two...`, I even try running `id username_one` and It seems to be reaching our AD DC fine.

**3.** Set the logging level of Samba to 5 and monitor for anything useful in /var/log/samba/. The only line that really jumps out to me is `smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED]`. However I can always provide the full log if it helps.

**Temporary Fix**

If I run `setfacl -Rm u:username:rwX directory_in_question` then the user will be able to make changes. Or if I change the permissions of the folder to `chmod o+rwx directory_in_question` then It works without a hitch. However, `chmod g+rwx directory_in_question` where I'm specifying the group directly with chmod doesn't work.

The smb.conf looks like this

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   security = ads

   workgroup = COMPANY_A
   realm = COMPANY_A.net

#   dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
   kerberos method = system keytab

   disable netbios = Yes
   load printers = No
   printing = bsd
   printcap name = /dev/null
   disable spoolss = Yes

## User mapping!! (to map old users on server)
   username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  # log level = 5

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

# Log level
#   log level = 5

   lm announce = no
   server max protocol = SMB3
   server min protocol = NT1
   client max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = NT1

[share]
   comment = Share folder
   path = /mnt/share_name
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   directory mask = 0744
   force directory mode = 02775
   create mask = 0664
   force create mode = 0664
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = no
   veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/
   vfs objects = streams_xattr
```

Realm List Info

```
realm list info

company_A.net
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: company_A.NET
  domain-name: company_A.net
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: winbind
  required-package: winbind
  required-package: libpam-winbind
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: COMPAND_A\%U
  login-policy: allow-any-login
company_A.net
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: company_A.NET
  domain-name: company_A.net
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
  permitted-logins:
  permitted-groups:
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with the MongoDB Realm database (tag)?

Answer (score 0):

Go and read the Samba wiki page again and then setup your smb.conf correctly, this time without sssd.

I also noticed this '## User mapping!! (to map old users on server)' , that isn't what the usermap is for (well, not in an AD domain).